# I can't seem to get a working synchronization script with WinSCP

Tags: batch-file, sftp, winscp

I've tried many different example scripts and none of them seem to work for me. Can someone help me troubleshoot?

The most recent attempt, straight from the example scripts:

bat:

```
winscp.com /script=script.txt /parameter // %1 "/internet/remotedirectory/%~n1%~x1"
```

txt:

```
open sftp://user:pword@sftp.address.gov -hostkey="ssh-rsa 1024 9c:b7:21:5c:ad:02:bb:30:c5:27:a5:bc:41:1a:ab:a0"
synchronize remote "%1%" "%2%"
```

I run this bat file and the window closes at: Authenticating with pre-entered password.

What I really want to do is synchronize the local folder to the remote folder, but for the sake of learning, I'm just trying to get any script working.

Previously, I had tried:

```
option batch abort
option confirm off
open sftp://user:pword@sftp.address.gov -hostkey="ssh-rsa 1024 9c:b7:21:5c:ad:02:bb:30:c5:27:a5:bc:41:1a:ab:a0"
synchronize local H:\LocalDirectory /internet/remotedirectory
exit
```

The cmd window shows:

```
Searching for host...
Connecting to host...
Authenticating...
Using username "user".
Authenticating with pre-entered password.
Authenticated.
Starting the session...
Session started.
Active session: [1] user@sftp.address.gov
Comparing...
Local 'internet/remotedirectory/' => Remote '%2%'
Error listing directory 'internet/remotedirectory/'.
Error retrieving file list for "internet/remotedirectory/\*.*".
System Error.  Code: 3.
The system cannot find the path specified
(A)bort, (R)etry, (S)kip: Abort
Error listing directory 'internet/remotedirectory/'.
Error retrieving file list for "internet/remotedirectory/\*.*".
System Error.  Code: 3.
The system cannot find the path specified

C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP>winscp.com /log=C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP\winscp.log /loglevel=2*
Opening session using command-line parameter in scripting is deprecated. Use 'open' command instead.
Searching for host...
Host "Files" does not exist.
winscp>
```

### **EDIT**

I added the local directory to pass along to the script (%2%):

```
open sftp://user:pword@sftp.address.gov -hostkey="ssh-rsa 1024 9c:b7:21:5c:ad:02:bb:30:c5:27:a5:bc:41:1a:ab:a0"
synchronize remote "%2%" "%1%"
```

Bat:

```
winscp.com /script=script.txt /parameter // %1 "internet/airpoll/out/%~n1%~x1" %2 "H:\APC\TSV\Airnow Queries\%~n1%~x1" 
winscp.com /log="C:\Users\me\Desktop\winscp.log" /loglevel=2*
```

Cmd window shows

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP>winscp.com /script=script.txt /parameter //  "internet/remotedirectory/"  "H:\localdirectory\"
Searching for host...
Connecting to host...
Authenticating...
Using username "user".
Authenticating with pre-entered password.
Authenticated.
Starting the session...
Session started.
Active session: [1] user@sftp.address.gov
Comparing...
Local 'H:\localdirectory' => Remote 'internet/remotedirectory'
Error listing directory 'internet/remotedirectory'.
No such file or directory.
Error code: 2
Error message from server: No such file
(A)bort, (R)etry, (S)kip: Abort

C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP>winscp.com /log="C:\Users\me\Desktop\winscp.log" /loglevel=2*
winscp>
```

I don't know why its saying 'no such directory' the directory is root/internet/remotedirectory, thats how it shows up in the WinSCP client.

Thanks for the help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
C:\Program Files (x86)\WinSCP>winscp.com /script=script.txt /parameter // "internet/remotedirectory"
```

There's only one parameter, the `internet/remotedirectory`. While the script needs two parameters.

It seems that you do not pass any argument to the batch file. So the `%1` in the batch file resolves to an empty string.